# Powering on specific pieces of circuitry in sequence

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

I'm trying to power on specific pieces of circuitry in sequence, and have one piece active at a time.  I thought a decade counter would be the way to go but most people seem to think a decade counter is a binary counter.  I'm trying to do this:

[image]

The best solution I've come up with so far is this:

[image]

Problem is this solution gets very resource intensive very fast, requiring more NOR gates for each line added.  What's the elegant solution for this?

Just to clarify, I only want one line active at any specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is, in principle headed roughly in the right direction, but there are a few problems. In the first place the 2-input OR gate is redundant, since the right-most FF ouput will force the NOR output low. More importantly, you show no means to reset the outputs to the correct starting state.

Generally the useful approach (using discrete logic) is to use a binary counter and a demultiplexer. The nominal part number for a demultiplexer is 74HC138/238, which will take in 3 address lines and some enable lines, and produce a 1-of-8 output. You can use 2 of these to decode 16 lines, and expand to virtually any number of outputs. The difference between the two types is that the 138 produces 1 low and 7 high, while the 238 produces 1 high and 7 low.

You also need to provide a reset to the counter to ensure that it starts at a count of zero. You might think that a counter would always do this when the power is applied, but this is not remotely true. Generating what is usually called a "power on reset" can be done in various ways, but usually a dedicated power management chip is used.

Comment: Thanks.  The demultiplexer approach was exactly what I was looking for.  I had no idea they existed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a microcontroller.  Something like a PIC10F or 12F would be ideal.  For sequencing three signals you can get away with a single 8-pin DIP IC (and a decoupling cap).  I'm happy to expand if you're willing to consider going down this path.

For anyone that wants to point out that there are SOT23-6 PIC's available, yes, this is true - but for an OP that is trying to use logic gates and flipflops, SMD design & loading and sharing ICSP lines with signalling lines are probably a few bridges too far.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the D-latches you may consider these:

Like someone already said you also need to use D-latches with a CLR pin and clear them with a differentiator.

1) You could make use of a RS flip-flop made of OR gates, set it by the Q of the first D-latch and reset it by the Q of the last one. Mind the type of logic you use.

[image]

2) You could wire the Q outputs of the D-latches in a wired-OR configuration.
[image]